# Playing an audio clip on specific slide images within a carousel/slider?

Tags: jquery

I have a basic slider with 3 images. Within the 3 images, I have 1 animated gif, which also has a audio clip linked to it. I want to be able to play the audio clip only when the animated gif slide comes up (the audio clip is only 3 seconds long). How would I go about this in jQuery?

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel-main" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
       <img src="image-1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       <img src="animated.gif" alt="">
       <embed src="audio/clip.mp3"></embed>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       <img src="image-3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#carousel-main').carousel({interval: 3200});
```

Comment: where is any of the other jQuery? for example, the stuff that shows each item in the carousel?

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the code. I'm using Bootstraps carousel.

Comment: html5? do you want to realize it with schillmania audio player or native `<audio>`tags which works starting with IE9 and all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert `embed` into `audio` ... if you're going to use HTML5 markup, might as well make it right.

```
<audio src="audio/clip.mp3"></audio>
```

Second, try this function out:

```
function playClip(){
    if($('.item').eq(1).hasClass('active')){
         $(this).next().get(0).play();
    }
}
```

This will play the clip if the correct slide is active, but you'll need to sync the call of this up with the rotation of the carousel:

```
window.setInterval(playClip,3200);
```

This should theoretically sync up the audio with the carousel, run the function each time the carousel shifts, and if the second one is active then play the clip. Not tested, but should work.

Comment: Great! Exactly what i was looking for